# Running monte carlo simulation over 100 runs and showing results on a graph or table using anylogic personal edition

Tags: anylogic

I am working on calculating the total evacuation time with random exit obstruction. My floor plan has 3 exits and I would like to obtain results for 1 of the exits, two exits or none presented on a table or graph.

I want to run a simulation over 100 times using monte carlo, as this can give me an average or solid result of my project but I'm unable to access the monte carlo simulation experiment feature because I don't have access to the professional version. Is there any other alternative to this? I can manually input the data on a table in an excel file for minimum 10 runs and find average but I want to know if there is any other way to do this using anylogic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.. create a parameter called dummy in your simulation and then create a parameter variation experiment. Make the dummy parameter change from 1 to 100 with step of 1.. this will run your simulation 100 times... and you can create graphs and all you want accordingly.

Alternatively, you can use the same parameter variation experiment and use 100 replications.

Comment: I've opted for the parameter variation experiment and use replications over 100. In my main I want to extract the time measure start and time measure end  into the table or graph. I got lost and not sure what to do from here.

Comment: You need to create your graph in the experiment and read outputs from Main. You can create Output or Statistics (e.g. startTime) from Analysis pallet in your Main agent and calculate and output whatever stats you like. In the After simulation/After Iteration Java actions of your experiment access that output using root (e.g. root.startTime) to update your graph.

Comment: Yes i'm having an error saying Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration.

Comment: I am not even sure if I'm making my graph correctly. I will post another question regarding this.